# Maven build failure in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

I've Jenkins as my CI/CD with over 30 multi-branch pipelines running and I have started getting this error at "artifactory configuration stage" when trying to deploy the artifactory to Jfrog. The snippet of my Jenkinsfile is as follows:

```
// Artifactory Intigration 
    stage('Artifactory configuration') {
         container('mvn') {

        // Obtain an Artifactory server instance, defined in Jenkins --> Manage:
        server = Artifactory.server 'dlight-jfrog'

        rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
        rtMaven.tool = 'mvn' // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
        rtMaven.opts = "-Denv=dev"
        rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
        rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot', server: server
        rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false // Disable artifacts deployment during Maven run

        buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
        }
    }
    
 // sonarqube configuration 

  stage('SonarQube analysis') {
     withSonarQubeEnv('dlight sonar') {
      //rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'package sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch.name=develop', buildInfo: buildInfo
      rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'package sonar:sonar', buildInfo: buildInfo
      } 
    }


  stage("Quality Gate"){
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { 
      def qg = waitForQualityGate() 
        if (qg.status != 'OK') {
          error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
        }
      }
    }
    
// build artifact    
    
    stage ('MVN Install') {
        rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'install', buildInfo: buildInfo
    }
```

And the pipeline aborts with this error message

```
Downloaded from central: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/libs-release/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.18.1/surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar (68 kB at 6.2 MB/s)

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Skipping pipeline-name
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD FAILURE
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Total time: 27.139 s
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: 2021-10-06T12:08:08Z
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Final Memory: 163M/962M
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project pipeline-name: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/piplelinename && /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java -javaagent:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.0/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.0-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/core-service-pipeline-name/target/jacoco.exec org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/core-service-pipelinename/target/surefire/surefire5994062267928659047tmp /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/pipeline-name/target/surefire/surefire_06380871570757565397tmp
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - -> [Help 1]
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: You are writing: `I have started getting this error at...` So there must be change which triggered that? What has been changed?

Comment: Nothing has been changed either on the Jenkinsfile or the application.

Comment: I doubt that...otherwise it could not change behaviour. I see two things. One is running `mvn package sonar:sonar` and another one is running `mvn install` why ? Duplication of a lot of steps... ?